# Generar un código de barras GS1 128 CON JASPER REPORTS Y COLOCARLE VARIOS IDENTIFICADORES DE APLICACION

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

Hola como están lo que pasa es lo siguiente, me encuentro generando un reporte en Jasper Reports el cual quiero que tenga el código GS1 128, el tipo por el momento que uso es el **UCC128**, este al momento yo le paso un **FIELD o PARAMETRO** `$F{codigo}` el cual ya contiene los consecutivos correspondientes (pueden ser el 415, 3900, 96, etc.) lo que pasa es que no se si este código de barras es el tipo correcto, y según veo en el Jasper hay una forma de pasar los identificadores de aplicación o esos consecutivos que mencione, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces a parte de saber si este tipo de código de barras es correcto ¿De que manera puedo para mas de un identificador de aplicación para que se coloque dentro de mi código de barras sin tener que colocarlo dentro del parámetro `$F{codigo}`? También si alguien puede compartirme documentación sobre Jasper Reports y como funciona seria genial, muchas gracias. Adjunto tambien imagen de como aparece el codigo de barras actualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]